# PHP not echoing with multiple conditions to sqli query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to echo the results of a query.  When I run the query in the phpmyadmin SQL box, it returns the right information.  When I add it to php, it doesn't echo anything if I add a second condition such as AND

Doesn't return anything

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM CwAp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'adurl' AND post_id = '31'";
 mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');


 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['meta_value'];
 }
```

Does return something

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM CwAp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'adurl'";
 mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');


 $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['meta_value'];
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure such a combination exists in your data? Perhaps show the output from `SELECT * FROM CwAp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'adurl'` so we can see the values for post_id. Also describe your intentions; perhaps you misunderstand the SQL operators – maybe you mean `OR` not `AND`.

Comment: I only want to get the meta_value if the meta_key is equal to adurl AND post_id 31.

This is the query in phpmyadmin which returns the correct information.

https://postimg.cc/Q9sgfCvB

Comment: Are you sure you have data where the key is `adurl` and the post_id is `31`? That's why I say, show us the SQL output.

Comment: You can also do `echo $query` and then paste that into phpmyadmin. If that gets results there but not in your php then my guess would be that your php is pointing to a different database.

Comment: Edited previous comment with image link to the phpmyadmin query

Comment: If I was in the wrong database, the query without the AND wouldn't work.

Comment: There's nothing in the information you've given us that's wrong. So without further information I can't see you getting an answer. Show us the working output from ` echo $row`.

Comment: Is there a `meta_value` column in your table ? you can try with `print_r($row);` or `var_dump($row);` to see what it contains.

Comment: This is what shows up without the AND.  Nothing shows up when I add the AND. Those aren't duplicate entries.  It's also pulling the revision history which is why I needed conditionals.

https://postimg.cc/BtbpkLXD

Comment: Did you try `[...] post_id = 31";` I mean without quotes ?

Comment: I just did now.  Nothing :-/


 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
 </body>

Comment: What about php version?  The server is 5.6.